# Select a single element of a list inside a summation

Tags: r, time, sum

I am trying to write a summattaion in R but I am running into problems. Here is my code:

```
team2_times= as_hms(c('00:19:31', '00:20:01', '00:20:22','00:20:31', '00:21:00'))
race_times <- data.frame(times = as_hms(c('00:19:19', '00:19:31', '00:19:32', '00:19:50', '00:20:35', '00:18:35', '00:19:59', '00:20:12', '00:20:14', '00:21:06', '00:17:31', '00:20:07', '00:20:30', '00:20:53', '00:21:13')), score = c(6, 12, 13, 15, 26, 2, 20, 41, 63, 94, 17, 47, 83, 121, 172))
n <- length(team2_times)
i <- 0:n
sum(race_times[which(abs(race_times$times - team2_times[i]) == min(abs(race_times$times - team2_times[i]))),2])
```

This works for other time vectors, but it does not for this one. Since the 3rd entry for team2_times vector is equally distant from two values, which() returns two values, and the summation cannot compute:

```
sum(race_times[which(abs(race_times$times - team2_times[3]) == min(abs(race_times$times - team2_times[3]))),2])
```

Is there a way that I can select the first output from the which() function (in this case, 63) so that the summation will continue for values without this problem?

I have tried other functions like sapply but it has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `which.min`:

```
race_times[which.min(abs(race_times$times - team2_times[3])), 2]
#> [1] 63

sapply(team2_times, function(x) race_times[which.min(abs(race_times$times - x)), 2])
#> [1] 12 20 63 83 94

sum(sapply(team2_times, function(x) race_times[which.min(abs(race_times$times - x)), 2]))
#> [1] 272
```

Or with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(race_times)[data.table(times = team2_times), on = "times", roll = "nearest"]$score
#> [1] 12 20 63 83 94

sum(setDT(race_times)[data.table(times = team2_times), on = "times", roll = "nearest"]$score)
#> [1] 272
```